# Форма существительного перед числительным

Tags: грамматика, числительные, управление

Недавно в интернете столкнулась со следующей фразой: "К сожалению, варианта только два: либо ты умираешь в иллюзиях, либо иллюзии умирают в тебе". Возник вопрос: правильно ли выбрана форма существительного "вариант" в этом предложении? Мне кажется, было бы правильнее сказать "вариантов только два".

P.S. Если возможно, подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком справочнике можно подробнее ознакомиться с правилами управления в подобных случаях!

Answer (score 2):

**Сколько вариантов? — Вариантов только два.**

Исходное структура: **Только два варианта** (есть). Это неполное предложение

При актуальном членении: Вариантов / только два.  Использована форма мн. числа, так как  числительное два, требующее ед. числа, удалено от существительного.

Пример:

**Вариантов только два:** либо искать прямые гарантии безопасности вовне, то есть у США, либо смотреть, не лучше ли войти в какие-то альянсы с Россией. [Павел Бурмистров. Что дальше // «Русский репортер», № 31 (61), 21-28 августа 2008, 2008]

Answer (score 0):

Количественно-именное сочетание (счётный оборот) "два варианта" при инверсии  обозначает приблизительное количество: "варинта два". Нельзя писать "варианта только два", корректно: "есть только два варианта", "вариантов было только два", но можно принять как разговорное: "вариантов (есть) только два".